# How to set up MCP430 Pins for SBW?

Tags: pcb-design, msp430, texas-instruments, jtag

Hello I'm a senior in college and I'm trying to develop a development board for the MSP430G2533IN20 Microcontroller, this is my first time working with TI MCU's, but I've worked with STM32 before.

I'm confused about how to connect the SBWTDIO, and SBWTCK pins for programming the board.

I know that for my chip, it can do 4-wire JTAG and 2-wire JTAG for programing the board. I decided to go with 2-wire JTAG because it will allow me more GPIO pins.

The main thing that is confusing me is that SBWTDIO and SBWTCK pins have other functions, does this mean that after the board is programed, I can use these pins for their other functions?

Also, to actually program the board, would I just use something like CCSTUDIO and the MSP-FET and connect to the pins directly and upload the program, or do I have to do some configuration on the board to make sure that pins are in SBWTDIO and SBWTCK mode?

TL;DR: How would I program a MSP430G2533IN20 on a custom board

[image: JTAG Capabilities for MCP430 Family]

Data Sheet for [MSP430G2533IN20](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430g2533.pdf?ts=1672440674890&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fsitesearch%252Fen-us%252Fdocs%252Funiversalsearch.tsp%253FlangPref%253Den-US%2526searchTerm%253DMSP430G2533IN20%2526nr%253D8)

JTAG [Programing Reference for MSP430](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau320aj/slau320aj.pdf?ts=1672389854514)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [MSP Debuggers User's Guide](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau647o/slau647o.pdf).

All you need to do is connect the pins as shown on page 22.

[image]

> The main thing that is confusing me is that SBWTDIO and SBWTCK pins have other functions, does this mean that after the board is programed, I can use these pins for their other functions?

The SBW pins aren't overloaded with many alternate functions.

[image]

You can configure SBWTDIO as NMI input. But you cannot disable the SBW function altogether.

You're probably thinking about the dedicated 4-wire JTAG pins (TDI/TCLK and TDO/TDI). These pins can be reconfigured for various different purposes. You'll lose the ability to debug over 4-wire JTAG, but 2-wire SBW will continue to work.

> Also, to actually program the board, would I just use something like CCSTUDIO and the MSP-FET and connect to the pins directly and upload the program, or do I have to do some configuration on the board to make sure that pins are in SBWTDIO and SBWTCK mode?

Both JTAG and SBW work out of the box; you don't need any special configuration. The debugger will be able to connect to either interface. All you have to do is setup the target configuration within CCS.